# iOS8 Self-Signed Certificates installed but still not trusted

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl-certificate

For reasons out of my control, I need to do iOS development against a platform using a self-signed certificate. It's a root certificate that has a specific IP address in its SAN.

When the certificate is installed in OSX under system account, all the browsers will now trust any visit to the given IP address normally.

Emailing that same certificate to an iOS8 device, and going through the install and trust steps now lists the certificate under installed profiles.

However, on the device, visits to the IP address still give the untrusted warning. This includes any requests in Safari, or an UIWebView.

If the certificate is installed and is a good certificate (works in OSX), why might it not work on device?

Comment: I've copied certificates (both .cer and .crt) from Google Drive to my iPhone, but I'm unsure how to install them. I'd appreciate any hints, simbolo and @daphtdazz. Thanks.

Comment: Here is what I figured out: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/321537/53510

Answer (score 3):

I think this applies to iOS 8 devices, but certainly to iOS 10.

As well as installing it from the email so it shows up in the profile, you also need to go to the very oddly hidden "General->About->Certificate Trust Settings" setting in Settings and "Enable full trust for root certificates" for your newly installed certificate. Then all webkit using apps on your device should trust that certificate with no new prompting.

Weird, huh.

Comment: Note: You must use iOS Mail app. Gmail won't let you install a cert!

Comment: Another way is to put it on a webserver and browse directly to it in Safari - that cuts down on the annoying extra step.

Comment: If you don't see anything under `Certificate Trust Settings` make sure you haven't exported the self signed cert as a PFX which includes the private key. It's a big security risk to have the private key available to anyone (!) - it's just a shame Apple doesn't give an explicit error. I was using `export-pfxcertificate` in powershell and switching to `export-certificate` allowed it to be shown under CTS.