# iOS 11, 12, and 13 installed certificates not trusted automatically (self signed)

Tags: ios

On our internal network, we use a self-signed CA certificate. This has worked fine for years, in both Safari and our iOS product, all the way through iOS 10. We simply install the CA certificate on any new device or simulator and everything works, even with ATS. This allows access to all of our internal test servers without having to trust each server individually.

Starting with iOS 11 the installed CA certificate no longer allows Safari or our app to trust the certificate for any of the servers. We receive the following relevant details with `CFNETWORK_DIAGNOSTICS` enabled for our app:

> Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=**-1200**
>   
> _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=**-9802**
>   
> _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=**3**
>   
> _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=**-9802**
>   
> NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.
>   
> NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?

I spent considerable time trying to resolve this issue, scouring StackOverflow and the rest of the web. Although we use AFNetworking in our app, that seems to be irrelevant, as Safari no longer trusts these servers via the CA. Disabling ATS via `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` allows access to the servers, but obviously isn't a solution.

No changes have been made to our `-URLSession:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler` code, and we have a proper (worked for years) implementation of challenge response via `challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust`.

I have re-evaluated and tested both the CA and server certificates every way I can think of, and they work everywhere except iOS 11. What might have changed in ATS for iOS 11 that could cause this issue?

Comment: Our QA team reported that any Apple device updated to iOS 11 can no longer use Safari or Chrome to access any internal https sites. The normal way of accepting self signed certificates that has worked for years and continues to work with non-upgraded devices no longer works. Looks like many people are having the same issue https://twitter.com/jfsiman/status/910269395959795712

Comment: This is also start to happen on macOS Mojave, and I can't find a resolution to it.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

While writing this question, I discovered the answer. Installing a CA from Safari no longer automatically trusts it. I had to manually trust it from the Certificate Trust Settings panel (also mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30479150/ios8-self-signed-certificates-installed-but-still-not-trusted)).

[image]

I debated canceling the question, but I thought it might be helpful to have some of the relevant code and log details someone might be looking for. Also, I never encountered the issue until iOS 11. I even went back and reconfirmed that it automatically works up through iOS 10.

I've never needed to touch that settings panel before, because any installed certificates were automatically trusted. Maybe it will change by the time iOS 11 ships, but I doubt it. Hopefully this helps save someone the time I wasted.

If anyone knows why this behaves differently for some people on different versions of iOS, I'd love to know in comments.

**Update 1**: Checking out the first iOS 12 beta, it looks like things remain the same. This question/answer/comments are still relevant on iOS 12.

**Update 2**: Same solution seems to be needed on iOS 13 beta builds as well.

Comment: Hi there - Unfortunately my certificate is not showing up in the Certificate Trust Settings - do you have any suggestions for this?

Comment: Your certificate may not showing up in the Certificate Trust Settings if your certificate is Blocked type.

Comment: Nice find - Noting that this has been the case since iOS 10.3. Here is the relevant support entry from apple: https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204477

Comment: @user3601148 your certificate must be CA, the root certificate. Some setup uses child certificate, so export that CA cert in your environment and install to iOS, then find it appearing in Certificate Trust Setting.

Comment: Just successfully did this on 12.4. Handy tip: once the cert is installed, search "mitmproxy" in the settings app to be prompted to jump straight to the Certificate Trust Settings page

Comment: @MattP You can accept your own answer to help future visitors notice it.

Answer (score 10):

I've been struggling with this for 3 days now while attempting to connect to a local API running Laravel valet. I finally figured it out. In my case I had to drag and drop over the LaravelValetCASelfSigned.pem file from `~/.config/valet/CA/LaravelValetCASelfSigned.pem`

After verifying the installing within the simulator I had to go to Settings > About > Certificate Trust Settings > and Enable the Laravel Valet VA Self Signed CN

Finally working!!!

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! I wasn't getting anywhere with Google until I stumbled across your reply. I've put a blog with (what is hopefully) a well optimised title up to help others looking for the same thing :) https://medium.com/@joevallender/trust-laravel-valet-self-signed-certificate-for-ios-development-869e63e096f1

Comment: Thanks for this! Finally it worked. Came here from the blog posted her above.

Answer (score 7):

Recommended solution is to install and trust a self-signed certificate (root). Assuming you created your own CA and the hierarchy of the certificated is correct you don't need to change the server trust evaluation. This is recommended because it doesn't require any changes in the code.

1. Generate CA and the certificates (you can use openssl: [Generating CA and self-signed certificates](https://blog.httpwatch.com/2013/12/12/five-tips-for-using-self-signed-ssl-certificates-with-ios/).
2. Install root certificate (*.cer file) on the device - you can open it by Safari and it should redirect you to Settings
3. When the certificated is installed, go to Certificate Trust Settings (Settings > General > About > Certificate Trust Settings) as in MattP answer.

If it is not possible then you need to change server trust evaluation.

More info in this document: [Technical Q&A QA1948 HTTPS and Test Servers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1948/_index.html)

Comment: I did not know about #3. Thank you so much! I looked for this for far longer than I would have liked to.

Comment: Thank you! I spent a couple of hours trying to work out why my own CA signed server cert was untrusted on iOS only. Nothing wrong with the cert. It was #3 above. I wonder why the trust setting is not with the CA Profiles area of iOS Settings.

Answer (score 5):

This has happened to me also, after undating to IOS11 on my iPhone. When I try to connect to the corporate network it bring up the corporate cert and says it isn't trusted. I press the 'trust' button and the connection fails and the cert does not appear in the trusted certs list.

Answer (score 1):

Apple hand three categories of certificates: `Trusted`, `Always Ask` and `Blocked`. You'll encounter the issue if your certificate's type on the `Blocked` and `Always Ask` list. On Safari it show’s like:
[image]

And you can find the type of `Always Ask` certificates on Settings > General > About > Certificate Trust Setting

There is the [List of available trusted root certificates in iOS 11](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208125)

[Blocking Trust for WoSign CA Free SSL Certificate G2](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204132)

Comment: There's no option in Settings that lets me always trust certificates?

Comment: Since updating my iphone6 to iOS 11, I have been encountering this issue. The certificate is provided by godaddy (I have no control over). The only way to get on the wifi network is to first forget the network, then enter credentials, then trust the certificate. The certificate does not show up in Certificate Trust Settings and I see no way to add one. The next time I sign onto the network, if I don’t first forget the network, will first prompt me to trust the certificate, then ask for credentials, then ask again to trust the certificate but the error then becomes login pw invalid.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not seeing the certificate under General->About->Certificate Trust Settings, then you probably do not have the ROOT CA installed. Very important -- needs to be a ROOT CA, not an intermediary CA.

I just answered a question here explaining how to obtain the ROOT CA and get things to show up: [How to install self-signed certificates in iOS 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49422164/how-to-install-self-signed-certificates-in-ios-11/52520343#52520343)

Answer (score 0):

I follow all recommendations and all requirements. I install my self signed root CA on my iPhone. I make it trusted. I put certificate signed with this root CA on my local development server and I still get certificated error on safari iOS. Working on all other platforms.