# WKWebView cannot load page with ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Tags: ios, macos, ssl-certificate, wkwebview

I'm using a `WKWebView` to load a web page in a test environment where  a self-signed cert is present.

`WKWebView` seems unable to load that web page since the certificate has the following issue:

> ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

With Safari, both iOS and macOS, if I open the page, I obtain he following message:

[image]

If I decide to proceed, I can load correctly the page. On the contrary, with `WKWebView`, there is no API that allows to bypass this type of checking.

I've tried to trust all the certs by using the following snippets but nothing happens:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {

    if let serverTrust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust {
        completionHandler(.useCredential, URLCredential(trust: serverTrust))
    } else {
        completionHandler(.cancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil)
    }
}
```

In my `Info.plist` file I've set `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent` to `YES`, as well with `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` to have backward compatibility.

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried installing your local root certificate on the device? you need to do that via Apple Configurator, create a Profile and install it on your device. The problem is that certificates signed with untrusted root certificates won't be trusted in any case.

Comment: @dirkgroten I'm going to try. Thanks. Do you have guide to share?

Comment: Actually it looks like you can email or AirDrop the certificate to yourself and then install it (important: the root certificate needs to have CN - Common Name). After that, don't forget to explicitely trust it: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44952985/ios-11-and-12-installed-certificates-not-trusted-automatically-self-signed#44952986) and [this link for openssl instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49422164/how-to-install-self-signed-certificates-in-ios-11)

Comment: @dirkgroten Thanks. Event trusting the certificate it does not work.

Comment: What about your `NSAppTransportSecurity` setting in Info.plist? Set `NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads` to `YES`

Comment: @dirkgroten You can find my answer. The problem is not due to certificate but to 3rd part cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the problem.

Previously I was using this technique to inject third part cookies in order to load a web page.

[How to set WKWebView cookie accept policy?](https://medium.com/@flexaddicted/how-to-set-wkwebview-cookie-accept-policy-d8a2d3b77420)

In iOS 12 this cannot used anymore due to https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=188691.

I'm wrapping my head around in order to find a solution...