# Secure connection can't be made

Tags: swift, https, certificate, alamofire, host

**Using**: `Alamofire 5`, `self-signed certificate`.
The certificate is stored in application resources
`AlamofireExtension(Bundle.main).certificates` - returns it.
**Session**:

```
    private let session: Session = {
        let manager = ServerTrustManager(evaluators: ["com.my.host.here": PinnedCertificatesTrustEvaluator(certificates: AlamofireExtension(Bundle.main).certificates, acceptSelfSignedCertificates: true, performDefaultValidation: false, validateHost: false)])
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        config.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 60
        config.timeoutIntervalForResource = 60
        config.httpMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 2
        return Session(configuration: config, serverTrustManager: manager)
    }()
```

**.plist** configuration:
[image]

**Purpose** is to use a self-signed certificate to validate the server without disabling validation and allowing insecure connections.
**Note** com.my.host.here is not my real hostname, I changed it for privacy reasons.
And here the result:

```
Task <715E277D-6BAA-4926-91AA-1060903D2924>.<1> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -1200 [3:-9802])   

my_app[12152:5481718] Task <715E277D-6BAA-4926-91AA-1060903D2924>.<1> finished with error [-1200] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, NSErrorPeerCertificateChainKey=(
    "<cert(0x160039a00) s: com.my.host.here i: com.my.host.here>"
), NSErrorClientCertificateStateKey=0, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://com.my.host.here:8043/some_end_point_here, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://com.my.host.here:8043/some_end_point_here, NSUnderlyingError=0x281354870 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerTrust=<SecTrustRef: 0x282f35320>, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9802, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9802, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates=(
    "<cert(0x160039a00) s: com.my.host.here i: com.my.host.here>"
)}}, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <715E277D-6BAA-4926-91AA-1060903D2924>.<1>"
), _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9802, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <715E277D-6BAA-4926-91AA-1060903D2924>.<1>, NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=<SecTrustRef: 0x282f35320>, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.}
```

**Questions is**: What is the problem? Is it a problem with the certificate, or with the server side settings? and maybe something else?

Comment: how do you run your alamofire requests? If you use it as `AF.request` - then it is your problem. you should use created `session`, but it is `private` in code sample, so I thought that it could be the issue.

Comment: Oh no, I use it as session.request of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads` to `YES`.

> **[NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsapptransportsecurity/nsexceptiondomains)**
>
> Set the value for this key to YES to allow insecure HTTP loads for the given domain, **or to be able
> to loosen the server trust evaluation requirements for HTTPS
> connections to the domain**, as described in [Performing Manual Server
> Trust Authentication](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/handling_an_authentication_challenge/performing_manual_server_trust_authentication).

Comment: I know about this, but setting this value to YES is allows insecure connection and loads, and in this case may loose trust evaluation. It’s not safety for the app and for the server. I want to use https only and only validated certificates.

Comment: @SergeyHleb then see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47395378/1135154, however this is not user-friendly workflow as it require manual actions in settings. You should sign your certificate with public Certificate Authority or disable `NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads` to be able to use self-signed certificate w/o installing root CA and enabling trust in settings. There will be no security issues as it still will be https (of course if server do not support http) and validated via pinned certificates.

Comment: is the only way to add a self signed certificate manually in the settings? all other methods allows insecure connections? only one way is to use simple certificate, generated by some certification center, and default evaluating?

Comment: yes, only manual installation. And don't say all other methods are insecure...You will make Manual Server Trust Authentication (see links above) as it described in apple docs. Otherwise you need to use trusted CA and usually pay for it.

Comment: ok, i will try manual trust autentication on monday and tell you about result. Thank you.

Comment: **Manual Server Trust Authentication** == `ServerTrustEvaluating` i.e. `PinnedCertificatesTrustEvaluator` in your case

Comment: But I can manually compare certificates. According with link you provided by, isn’t it?

Comment: yes, you can. but this is exactly what Alamofire's `PinnedCertificatesTrustEvaluator` doing.

Comment: Yeah, but I can do it how I need. For example, compare fingerprints, isn’t it?